# max-content not working in IE 10, 11, 12 and probably the rest to come?

Tags: internet-explorer, navigation, width

I am having trouble with IE behaving. I am wanting my navigation to be centralised.

The navigation will have the odd link changed now and then so I was wanting to use max-content; regardless of what is in the navigation the container width is always the right size without me having to work it out every time.

This works perfect in Chrome, FF, Opera and pretty much every browser except IE.  I have not really been able to find a legit or full answer about this so I ask: Why does IE not support width: max-content?

Also, is there a way to force IE to behave?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, [status.modern.ie](https://status.modern.ie/) reports that the [CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/) is not currently supported in any version of IE, but that it's currently "[under consideration](https://status.modern.ie/cssintrinsicsizing)"

It may be supported at some point in the future.  If you like, you can help that happen by [voting for support](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/6263702-css-intrinsic-sizing) at the [IE UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform) site.

The [object-fit polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit/) seems like a possible alternative, but you'd likely need to test it against your specific needs.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Ah right, well, that is no good.  You'd have thought they realised they need more support these days but hey ho what can you do.  Thank you very much Lance, greatly appreciated.